# Projecting Grouped Tuples in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a collection of tuples of the form (t,a,b) that I want to group by b in Pig. Once grouped, I want to filter out b from the tuples in each group and generate a bag of filtered tuples per group.

As an example, assume we have
(1,2,1)
(2,0,1)
(3,4,2)
(4,1,2)
(5,2,3)

The pig script would produce 
{(1,2),(2,0)}
{(3,4),(4,1)}
{(5,2)}

The question is: how do I go about producing this result? I'm used to seeing examples where aggregation operations follow a group by operation. It's less clear to me how to filter the tuples and return them in a bag. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 8):

Turns out what I was looking for is the syntax for nested projection in Pig.

If one has tuples of the form (t,a,b) and wants to drop b after the group by, it is done this way.

```
grouped = GROUP tups BY b;
result = FOREACH grouped GENERATE tup.(t,a);
```

See the "Nested Projection" section on the PigLatin page. http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigLatin